# I am using gridLayout with spanCount 2 but I want to show spanCount 1 after every 10 items

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gridview, gridlayoutmanager

```
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,2);

recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

I am trying this but this is not working and no any error find I search everywhere but find nothing can any one help.

```
if(gridLayoutManager.getItemCount() == 10){gridLayoutManager.setSpanCount(1);}else{gridLayoutManager.setSpanCount(2);
}
```

Comment: You can take 2 viewType in Recyclerview and before the setting, the list to the adapter defines view type according to the position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is part of my code to set 3 items per row and spanCount 1 after every 9 items
you can convert this kotlin code to java and set your constraints

```
private val SHOP_TYPE = 1
private val AD_TYPE = 2

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    if(viewType == SHOP_TYPE) {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_shop_home, parent, false)
        return ShopViewHolder(view)
    }
    else {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_ad_search, parent, false)
        return AdsViewHolder(view)
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return shopsList.size + adsList.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val countAds = (position + 1) / 10
    val indexAd = if(((position + 1) / 10) - 1 < 0) 0 else ((position + 1) / 10) - 1
    val isLastOne = (position + 1) == (shopsList.size + adsList.size)
    if((position + 1) % 10 == 0 || isLastOne) {
        val adsHolder = holder as AdsViewHolder
        adsHolder.bind(adsList[indexAd], adsClickListener)
    }
    else {
        val shopHolder = holder as ShopViewHolder
        shopHolder.bind(shopsList[position - countAds], shopClickListener)
    }
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    if((position + 1) % 10 == 0 || (position + 1) == (shopsList.size + adsList.size))
        return AD_TYPE
    return SHOP_TYPE
}

open class ViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
}

class ShopViewHolder(view: View): ViewHolder(view) {

}

class AdsViewHolder(private val view: View): ViewHolder(view) {
    
}
```

and you set this code on your fragment/activity

```
private fun setRecyclerView() {
    searchAdapter = SearchAdapter(shopsList, adsList)
    val gridLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(requireContext(), 3)
    gridLayoutManager.spanSizeLookup = object : GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        override fun getSpanSize(position: Int): Int {
            if((position + 1) % 10 == 0 || (position + 1) == (shopsList.size + adsList.size))
                return 3
            return 1
        }
    }
    rootView.rvSearch.layoutManager = gridLayoutManager
    rootView.rvSearch.setHasFixedSize(true)
    rootView.rvSearch.adapter = searchAdapter
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val gridLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 2)
gridLayoutManager.spanSizeLookup = object : GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    override fun getSpanSize(position: Int): Int {
        return if (position % 10 == 0) 2 else 1
    }
}
rv.layoutManager = gridLayoutManager
```

I used kotlin, you can rewrite it with Java, just use the gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup() method in Java. Pay attention to that the spanSize means weight, instead of count.